# JavaFX error while getting column/row index

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I've encountered a weird behaviour in JavaFX.
In short:

I have a Grid Pane and add an element to position lets say (0, 0. Or whatever, as long as row is 0 or column is 0) than the .fxml file doesn't fill the row/column property and leaves it without, which is default to 0. But if I leave it this way and want implement for example listener, which gets the position of clicked element using GridPane.getColumnIndex(Node); then it throws an exception and the only way to make it work is to manually edit the .fxml file and add those column = 0 / row = 0.

Is this a bug? A meant behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. Note that the [Javadocs for `GridPane.getRowIndex(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#getRowIndex-javafx.scene.Node-) say

> Returns the child's row index constraint if set.
>
> **Returns**
>
> the row index for the child or null if no row index was set

So if they are not set, the value returned is not the default value used in layout, but `null`.

If you don't set the `GridPane.columnIndex` and `GridPane.rowIndex` constraints on a `Node` , and add it to a `GridPane`'s list of child nodes, default values will be used: namely 0 for these properties. (The other values also have default values, e.g. if no `columnSpan` is set, the default value is `1`. This means that default values can be used without adding to the memory consumption of the node.)

The way the layout constraints work on a node placed in a cell is that values are added to the `Node`'s properties with some specific keys. (The `Node.getProperties()` method just returns a `Map<Object, Object>` which can contain arbitrary key-value mappings. So the code

```
    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    for (int x = 0 ; x < 8; x++) {
        for (int y = 0 ; y < 8 ; y++) {
            Label label = new Label(String.format("Cell [%d, %d]", x, y));
            root.getChildren().add(label);
            GridPane.setColumnIndex(label, x);
            GridPane.setRowIndex(label, y);
        }
    }
```

turns out to be equivalent to

```
    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    for (int x = 0 ; x < 8; x++) {
        for (int y = 0 ; y < 8 ; y++) {
            Label label = new Label(String.format("Cell [%d, %d]", x, y));
            root.getChildren().add(label);
            label.getProperties().put("gridpane-column", new Integer(x));
            label.getProperties().put("gridpane-row", new Integer(y));
        }
    }
```

though of course the first version is much more robust (and clear); you should never use the second version.

If you do

```
Integer x = GridPane.getColumnIndex(node);
```

that method is (I assume, I haven't checked the source code) implemented so it is identical to calling

```
Integer x = (Integer)node.getProperties().get("gridpane-column");
```

If you didn't set a column index, then there is no such mapping in the properties map, so in this case `x` is `null`.

If you do

```
int x = GridPane.getColumnIndex(node);
```

and haven't set a column index, then (because you are implicitly unboxing the returned `Integer` into an `int`), you are effectively calling

```
int x = ((Integer)node.getProperties().get("gridpane-column")).intValue();
```

Here, if the column index has not been set, `node.getProperties().get(...)` returns `null` (as also specified by the `GridPane.getColumnIndex(...)` documentation) , so you get a `NullPointerException` when you implicitly invoke `intValue()`.

Comment: Scenebuilder likes to treat 0 as not set and nulls the constraint field. So manually set the constraints in the fxml file if added there. e.g <Canvas GridPane.columnIndex=”0” GidPan.rowIndex=”0”>.